# Graylog: Move configuration of graylog between environments

Tags: graylog2, graylog

I'm looking solution for moving configuration from test environment to prod environment for graylog.
Once I configure inputs and streams on test environment I would like easily move this configuration to production. Doing it manually can produce some bugs ex. by misspelling the correct name.

How to do that? Is there an option to export and import graylog configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only want to migrate Inputs (incl. Extractors), Streams, Dashboards, and Lookup Tables (incl. Data Adapters and Lookup Caches), you can use Content Packs for that.

See System/Content Packs in the web interface.